# Flexbox spacing items in nav bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to space items within a nav bar where I have *tags* and search bar. I tried space-between, but not show how to properly position the search bar to get it to be slightly larger. Is this some combo of flex-end?

## Attempt

[image]

## Mock-Up

[image: ![enter image description here]

The box on the right should be slightly larger.

#### Code

##### Container

```js
const TagsContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15px;
`

export default function Tags() {
    return (
        <TagsContainer>
            <Tag>Algorithms</Tag>
            <Tag>Videos</Tag>
            <Tag>Books</Tag>
            <Tag>Tutorials</Tag>
            <Tag>Health</Tag>
            <Tag>Finance</Tag>
            <Tag>Rants</Tag>
            <Tag>Stream</Tag>
            <Tag>Music</Tag>
            <Search />
        </TagsContainer>
    )
}
```

##### Tag

```js
const TagContainer = styled.div`
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 40px;
    opacity: .8;
    text-align: center;
`

const TagStyle = styled.span`
    font-family: 'Lora';
    min-width: 80px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 15px;
`

export default function Tag({ children }) {
    return (
        <>
            <TagContainer>
                <TagStyle>
                    { children }
                </TagStyle>
            </TagContainer>
        </>
    )
}
```

##### Search

```
const SearchContainer = styled.div`
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 2;
    min-height: 40px;
    height: 100%;
    
`

export default function Search() {
    return (
        <>
            <SearchContainer>
                This is a search box
            </SearchContainer>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Try using `gap:2px` (or the number you want) in TagsContainer

Comment: Like this I guess? https://jsfiddle.net/mwok3tx8/

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-grow: 1;`  to `TagContainer` to allow all flex items to *grow*